# Quadratic congruence equation: must I use trial & error?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

So I'm studying number theory, and my book said that 
$$ x^2 + 5x + 7 \equiv 0 \pmod n $$
had at least four solutions for 1<n<20. I found four (n=3,7,13,19) but n=19 was tricky: I had to replace 7 with -50, which I assume was legit since $ 7 \equiv -50 \pmod {19}  $ . Is this the only way to find the solution, by using trial and error to replace coefficients until you can complete the square?

Comment: See the linked dupes for how to solve modular quadratics. It's not clear what you mean by "at least four solutions". Please clarify. Better: state precisely what is claimed in your book instead of paraphrasing it.

Comment: Are you familiar with [quadratic reciprocity?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity) If so you can use that to find the the prime moduli where the discriminant $-3\,$ is a square, viz. $\,p\equiv 1\pmod 3\ \ $

Comment: Noted that since $1\lt n\lt20$ we can solve easily this problem by brute force.